# Github webhook with NextJs

Tags: express, github, next.js

I am working on a NextJS project and I want to use a github webhook to deploy a script that has deployment instructions.

I have setup a push webhook in github

I tried to add the following code in my server.ts file and for now testing this with ngrok

```
// testing
server.post("/webhooks/github", function(req, res) {
  var sender = req.body.sender;
  var branch = req.body.ref;

  if (branch.indexOf("master") > -1 && sender.login === githubUsername) {
    deploy(res);
  }
});

function deploy(res: any) {
  childProcess.exec("sh deploy.sh", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err, stderr);
      return res.send(500);
    }
    console.log(stdout);
    res.send(200);
  });
}
```

this file is my node file for the nextJS application

however I am getting a 502 in my ngrok logs

I would like to know where in my NextJS application should I put this webhook endpoint to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could get this to work is by creating another app on the same server ( I used express ) and then used an endpoint on that as github webhook and from there I ran the deploy script.

simple solution and hope this helps somebody..

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but this worked for me:

```
// pages/api/webhooks/github.js
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const crypto = require("crypto");

// Handle GitHub Webhooks
export default function handler(req, res) {
    try {
        console.log("Incoming Request");
        if (req.method !== 'POST') {
            res.send(404);
            return;
        }
        let sig =
            "sha256=" +
            crypto
                .createHmac("sha256", process.env.WEBHOOKS_SECRET)
                .update(JSON.stringify(req.body))
                .digest("hex");
        if (
            req.headers["x-hub-signature-256"] === sig &&
            req.body?.ref === "refs/heads/main" &&
            process.env.REPO_PATH
        ) {
            exec(
                "cd " +
                    process.env.REPO_PATH +
                    " && git pull && npm install && npm run build && pm2 restart app"
            );
            console.log("GitHub Webhook ran successfully");
            res.end();
            return;
        }
        console.log("GitHub Webhook failed");
        res.end();
        return;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```